# updating a variable in an ASP.NET MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this string variable call "status" which is updated by a serial port connection I've made. the "status" show's if u are connected to the serial port or not.
I've made a simple 2 buttons view. one opens the connection and the other close it.
i want to be able to auto update the status of the connection inside the view.
i guess i need to use some kind of timer which shows the string inside "status" every given time, but i have no clue on how to do it..

This is my HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{   
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
      return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CheckStatus()
    {
    return Json(new { status = "active" });
    }
}
```

and this is my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    // poll every 5 seconds
    setInterval('checkStatus()', 5000);
}

function checkStatus() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Home/CheckStatus',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(xhr_data) {
            if(xhr_data.status == 'active') {
                // this would just disable the "Open" button
                $('#btnOpen').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you need a polling mechanism in place. Have you tried anything yet? There are several ways to do this.

Comment: i would love to hear more about it

Comment: Please come with a case where you actual tried to solve it yourself and are stuck.

Comment: @Asaf Nevo The goal here is to help StackOverflow help you. I posted an answer below, but it's based on a problem I had. A quick Google search on polling mechanisms would give you a lot of ideas about implementation. Your problem as described here isn't specific enough to solve.

Comment: this is my code.. will be thankful if could tell me whats wrong with it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume you can use jQuery, and that you have a Controller action that looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public class StatusController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult CheckStatus()
    {
        return Json(new { status = "active" });
    }
}
```

Then, in your view add the following script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // poll every 5 seconds
        setInterval('checkStatus()', 5000);
    }

    function checkStatus() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Status/CheckStatus',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(xhr_data) {
                if(xhr_data.status == 'active') {
                    // this would just disable the "Open" button
                    $('#btnOpen').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i actually have a simple string inside a model and i'm showing it in the view. i just want the view to update it every given time.

Comment: @Asaf Nevo That's not part of your OP. Can you please modify and be as descriptive as possible?

Comment: will do.
i'm using a modbus RTU protocol to communicate with a flow meter i have.

Comment: sorry, pressed the enter by mistake.
i want to get information from the modbus every 500 ms.
the information i've got from it, is stored in a class which have a string var name "status". i want to show this string in the view, and update it automaticly every 500 ms.

Comment: it's pretty simple.. i have a string in a model. i have this view who shows this string.
i want the view to check for update in the string every 500 ms and show it. i need the view to be "live". it's like refreshing just a part of the view

Comment: @Asaf Nevo That's what my code does--you're going to need your own implementation in the controller action that uses your model and calls `return Json(yourModel);` Then you need to do whatever you want in the `jQuery.ajax` success callback function. You keep saying it's simple without showing us any code, so change mine or show us yours.

Comment: you're right, i'm not showing code because i didn't even know how to start it. i will try to implement yours and will update soon. Thanks !

Comment: ok.
for test i've copy and paste your code with minor changes for my site:

Comment: this is my HomeController:

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        
        public ActionResult Index()
        {


            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult CheckStatus()
        {
        return Json(new { status = "active" });
        }

    }

Comment: this is my view: <br/>
' 
<script type="text/javascript">  <br/>
    $(function() {  <br/>
        // poll every 5 seconds  
        setInterval('checkStatus()', 5000);
    }

    function checkStatus() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Home/CheckStatus',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(xhr_data) {
                if(xhr_data.status == 'active') {
                    // this would just disable the "Open" button
                    $('#btnOpen').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
 '

Comment: and offcaurse i have a button:
`  <input type="button" id="btnOpen" value="Open"> `

Comment: @Asaf Nevo Good grief--please post this code in the original post. Click the "edit" button. It's too early to parse code in comments

Comment: for some reason it didn't add it but i have a button in the View:
<input type="button" id="btnOpen" value="Open">

Comment: ? can you please check my code's changes to see what's wrong ?

Comment: @Asaf Nevo You've either copied incorrectly, or you're missing parenthesis. You don't have a closing `</script>` tag. You didn't close your first call `$(function() { ... });`. Does the polling start? Does the ajax request succeed? What's in the response? Have you debugged the JavaScript code?